# Автовыполнение команд в Linux при каждом успешном вводе пароля пользователя

Tags: linux, linux-mint, автозапуск

мне нужно добавить автовыполнение команд при каждом успешном вводе пароля пользователя в Linux Mint. Я пробовал это сделать через изменение файлов `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, но проблема в том, что это работает только при однократном входе в систему. Если я заблокирую компьютер при помощи сочетания клавиш `Ctrl+Alt+L`, а затем снова войду в систему, то автовыполнение команд не произойдет. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы решить данную проблему?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974199/how-to-run-a-script-at-screen-lock-unlocks-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `pam_exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме предложенного варианта с использованием dbus, навскидку, ещё два варианта:

1. Натравить *inotify* на файл */var/log/auth.log*. Тогда, при любом событии логирования Ваш процесс получит об этом уведомление и сможет проанализировать - что именно произошло.
2. Воспользоваться пакетом *auditd*. Думаю, что там что-то по этому поводу должно быть.